# Menu can't go directly to a page

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have menu which is has sub menus.

```
<li>
   <a href="#lead" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Lead</span> <i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <div id="lead" class="collapse ">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#quotation" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>&nbsp;Quotation </span><i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <div id="quotation" class="collapse ">
                  <ul class="nav">
                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/cquotation"; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Create Quotation</a></li>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/qsummary"; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Quotation Summary</a></li>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/squotation"; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Send Quotation</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
```

When I clicked it, I can not go directly to the page. I have to right-clicked on it to go to the desired page. 
Here's an example of my controller

```
public function cquotation(){
        $data = $this->salesModel->showCustomer();
        $this->load->view('v_navbar');
        $this->load->view('v_leftside');
        $this->load->view('v_cquotation',array('data'=>$data));
    }
```

Do you guys have any idea what's wrong with it?
I'm totally confused

Comment: Try to replace `a` outside `li`, it should works

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"` on every hyperlink?. your code has `data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"` in every hyperlink.Bootstrap will prevent the default click event of a href .So remove every `data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"` part of a href in your code and it will work.

```
<li>
  <a href="#lead" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#lead"  class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Lead</span> <i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <div id="lead" class="collapse ">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#quotation" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>&nbsp;Quotation </span><i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <div id="quotation" class="collapse ">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/cquotation"; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Create Quotation</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/qsummary"; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Quotation Summary</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/SalesAdmin/squotation"; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Send Quotation</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Clearly. It wont work even if u put `a` outside `li` . here is an  Example of data-toggle on hyperlink (bootstrap css) https://codepen.io/jayakrishnancn/pen/ybWBee. If my ansewer found useful please accept  as answer . Ty